# How do I make a toast from a non activity class?

Tags: android, toast

I have a class that I am using to get GPS data within my activity. In the constructor I pass it the activity's context:

```
gpsFetcher = new GPSFetcher(this);
```

and in the gpsFetcher class I have:

```
this.context = c.getApplicationContext();
```

OR just

```
this.context = c;
```

and then I call the toast with:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "sometext", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

But it never shows up... Is there something I'm missing? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling `Toast.show();`? If not, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466087/cannot-display-toast-from-an-activity-other-than-my-main-activity

Comment: No, see the answer below... Facepalm. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you forgetting `Toast#show`?

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "sometext", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Comment: DOH! Yeah, that's the problem... I even had put it in other places I just wasn't getting to them because I was stopping when this one didn't show up! Mondays... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must call `show()` as well:

`Toast.makeText(context, "sometext", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question but I solved it.!! In the non-activity class , you just announce a "public static String". Then in your MainActivity or other activity , you can directly use Toast.

In my case , I declare a non-activity class NoteDB. so I declare  `public static String S` in the class . (You can change S value in the class. Then in my MainActivity , I announce

```
Toast(MainActivity.this, NoteDB.S ,TOAST.SHORT_LENTGH).show();
```

It works well.

Comment: Application context...? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 0):

To display a Toast in a Non-Activity Java class, add the Context in the constructor of the java class

[Here PrizeMethods is my java class]

```
public class PrizeMethods {
    Context context;
    public PrizeMethods(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
   }
```

and where you are instancing this class in your activity (making an object of it, using it in your main activity), add the context as a parameter.

Like this:

```
 PrizeMethods pm=new PrizeMethods(this);
```

after that inside your java class, you can create a toast like this:

```
 Toast.makeText(context, "toast inside class!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```