# How to display a Toast message in from a class that doesn't extend Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, toast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a toast from a non activity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543769/how-do-i-make-a-toast-from-a-non-activity-class)

How can I create and show a `Toast` message from a class which does not extended the `Activity` class? I'm using this class in another class that is extended by `Activity`.

Comment: u mean liek this

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(),
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: pls post the code to know with ease.

Comment: Displaying a Toast requires a reference to Context object. You can pass a context or activity object to the class where you want to create a Toast.

Comment: try with getActivity() wherever u use context

Comment: Not a duplicate question. That is another problem, than in the topic.

Answer (score 17):

You need a context Reference. Just have a helper method like

```
  public static void showToastMethod(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "mymessage ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: my method which use to show toast in try catch block  is static

Comment: This seems like a great way to leak a context. Rather pass the context as an argument to `showToastMethod()` and use it from there. Holding a permanent reference to it can be bad if an instance of your class lives longer than the activity/service/.. to which the context belongs. Making that reference static doesn't make it better, rather worse.

Comment: yes it is. It is a bit boring editing and re-editing in order to meet the requirement of a (not) customer

Answer (score 5):

---------------------- New Modular Version ------------------------

Create an Interface

```
 public interface ShowToast {
      public onShowToast (String message); [additionally you can pass toast duration]
}
```

In Activity class, implement this interface and write Toast method to show message.

```
public class ActivityClass extends Activity implements ShowToast{

  public giveCallToNonActivityClass(){
     new NonActivityClass(this); //Here we're passing interface impl reference.
  }

  public onShowToast (String message) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityClass.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Sample NonActivityClass will look like:

```
public class NonActivityClass {

  public NonActivityClass (ShowToast interfaceImpl) {
       interfaceImpl.onShowToast("I'm calling Toast from Non Activity ");
  }
}
```

Earlier version was too old to refer. Hope this more modular approach help.

-------------------------------- Old Version 2012 ----------------------------

You can pass context of that activity to your class by passing value to nonActivity class

example:

```
new NonActivityClass(Activityclass.this) ;
```

and as in above answer

```
new MyClass(ActivityClass.this);
```

In NonActivityClass

```
public class NonActivityClass {

  public NonActivityClass (Context context) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "mymessage ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

Hope this works for you...

Comment: its not worth to make tight coupling for showing toast